# Spring beans loaded multiple times

Tags: java, spring, matlab, cxf

I am writing Apache CXF web services and use Spring for loading my beans. My only bean is calling external process (MATLAB) from Java. My beans definition looks as below:

```xml
<bean id="matlabEngine" class="org.burch.pca.matlab.MatlabEngine"
    init-method="start" scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg value="${matlab.engine.path}"></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
    <property name="searchContextAttributes" value="true" />
    <property name="contextOverride" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:/pca-engine.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Piece of my MatlabEngine bean is as below:

```java
/**
 * Path to MATLAB engine.
 */
private String pathToEngine;

public MatlabEngine(String pathToEngine) throws MatlabConnectionException, MatlabInvocationException{
    super();
    setPathToEngine(pathToEngine);
}

/**
 * Starts engine and goes to path defined by argument
 * @param pathToEngine
 * @throws MatlabConnectionException
 * @throws MatlabInvocationException
 */
public void start() throws MatlabConnectionException, MatlabInvocationException{
  //Create a factory
  RemoteMatlabProxyFactory factory = new RemoteMatlabProxyFactory();

  //Get a proxy, launching MATLAB in the process
  proxy = factory.getProxy();

  //Display welcoming messages in MATLAB Command Window
  proxy.eval(MatlabCommandsRegistry.disp(MATLAB_ENGINE_WELCOME_1));
  proxy.eval(MatlabCommandsRegistry.disp(MATLAB_ENGINE_WELCOME_2));

  if(pathToEngine!= null && !"".equals(pathToEngine)){
      logM("Switching to engine directory...");
      String goToEngineRootDir = MatlabCommandsRegistry.cd(pathToEngine);
      proxy.eval(goToEngineRootDir);
      logM("Sucessfully changed engine dir to "+pathToEngine);
  }
}
```

When I deploy web services in Tomcat, it brings up MATLAB process nicely (bean gets loaded).

However, when I create client request to web service endpoint with this code:

```java
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();

    factory.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
    factory.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
    factory.setServiceClass(UploadService.class);
    factory.setAddress("http://localhost:8080/auth-ws-1.0.0/services/upload");
    UploadService client = (UploadService) factory.create();

    UploadEntity resume=new UploadEntity();
    resume.setFileName("Image490");
    resume.setFileType("jpg");

    //Work arround data handler....
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(new File("C:\\Users\\Pictures\\thumb.png"));
    DataHandler dataHandle = new DataHandler(source);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    dataHandle.writeTo(stream);
    resume.setPayload(stream.toByteArray());
    client.uploadFile(resume);
    System.exit(0);

}
```

my server brings out new instance of MATLAB process (bean gets loaded again - very heavy and undesirable). What could I do to have only one bean which will be used to serve all processing and all requests? I am new to Spring, and I am thinking that my problem is that I am dealing with multiple contexts here. I want them to share a single instance of a singleton bean but don't know how to manage this.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Do you actually need the functionality of the ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer class?  You could probably use the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer class instead if you're not attempting to parse context parameters in web.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable singleton mode for you bean.

Look at this: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-modes

Bean defenition may looks like this:

```
<!-- Spring property loading bean -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" singleton="true">
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
    <property name="searchContextAttributes" value="true" />
    <property name="contextOverride" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:/pca-engine.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I think you should manage MATLAB process lifecircle wisely to decrease resource loading.

Comment: Spring beans are singletons by default. I resolved the issue after I realized that my Spring beans are not wired to the CXF web service endpoints. Now I have only one instance of MATLAB engine bean, and it works great.